# Ubuntu: fix screen resolution for "unknown display" xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution

My Ubuntu display is set to `1024x768` for `Unknown display`:

[image]

My monitor is capable of `1920x1080`. Can someone please provide step-by-step instructions to fix this? I tried the following, based on other Q&As:

```
aloha@aloha-MS-7A68:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
  1280x1024 (0x2b1) 109.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
  1920x1080 (0x2b2) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
aloha@aloha-MS-7A68:~$ xrandr --output 0x2b1 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output (null) not found; ignoring
```

Here is my successfully installed driver:

[image]

I also tried:

```
cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Comment: Good point. It's possible I messed up my Nvidia graphics drivers while trying to install CUDA.